# find() return the latest value only on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, find, return-value

I have this collection in MongoDB that contains the following entries. I'm using Robo3T to run the query.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx1"),
    "Evaluation Date" : "2021-09-09",
    "Results" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "ABCD",
            "Version" : "3.2.x"
        }
    ]

    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx2"),
    "Evaluation Date" : "2022-09-09",
    "Results" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "ABxD",
            "Version" : "5.2.x"
        }
    ]

}
```

This document contains multiple entries of similar format. Now, I need to extract the latest value for "Version".
Expected output:

> 5.2.x

---

Measures I've taken so far:

(1) I've only tried findOne() and while I was able to extract the value of "Version": `db.getCollection('TestCollectionName').findOne().Results[0].Version`
...only the oldest entry was returned.

> 3.2.x

(2) Using the `find().sort().limit()` like below, returns the entire document for the latest entry and not just the data value that I wanted; `db.getCollection('TestCollectionName').find({}).sort({"Results.Version":-1}).limit(1)`
Results below:

> "_id" : ObjectId("xxx2"),
> "Evaluation Date" : "2022-09-09",
> "Results" : [
> {
> "Name" : "ABxD",
> "Version" : "5.2.x"
> }
> ]

(3) I've tried to use `sort()` and `limit()` alongside `findOne()` but I've read that findOne is maybe deprecated and also not compatible with sort. And thus, resulting to an error.

(4) Finally, if I try to use sort and limit on find like this: `db.getCollection('LD_exit_Evaluation_Result_MFC525').find({"Results.New"}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)` I would get an unexpected token error.

---

What would be a good measure for this?
Did I simply mistake to/remove a bracket or need to reorder the syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but maybe this could be what are you looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      lastResult: {
        "$last": "$Results"
      }, 
    }, 
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      version: "$lastResult.Version",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

It uses aggregate with some operators: the first `$project` calculate a new field called `lastResult` with the last element of each array using `$last` operator. The second `$project` is just to clean the output. If you need the `_id` reference, just remove `_id: 0` or change its value to `1`.

You can check how it works here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jwqulFtCh6b

Hope I helped